# locate/align picture of circuit board, extract colored dots from relative locations

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this PCB with the black components containing some colored dots. For a quality inspection I want to check all the dots und check, if they have the right color, which works pretty good. But if the PCB is just rotated or translated a little bit, this method will fail. Do you have any ideas, how to make this method more robust?

one component has a red sticker in this example
[image: This is my test image test.jpg]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Settings
confidentMax = 60
confidentMin = 40

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

pos2 = [96,205]
pos1 = [158,205]
positions = [pos1, pos2]
result = {}

dataContainer = []
for pos in positions:
    data = []
    img_part = img[pos[1]-15:pos[1]+15,pos[0]-15:pos[0]+15,:]
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img_part, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    data.append(pos)
    data.append(img_part)
    dataContainer.append(data)

for data in dataContainer:
    #convert image to HSV
    my_img = cv2.cvtColor(data[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    #check for reds
    # lower boundary RED color range values; Hue (0 - 10)
    lower1 = np.array([0, 100, 20])
    upper1 = np.array([10, 255, 255])
    # upper boundary RED color range values; Hue (160 - 180)
    lower2 = np.array([160,100,20])
    upper2 = np.array([179,255,255])
    lower_mask = cv2.inRange(my_img, lower1, upper1)
    upper_mask = cv2.inRange(my_img, lower2, upper2)
    full_mask = lower_mask + upper_mask
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(my_img, my_img, mask=full_mask)
    number = np.count_nonzero(full_mask)
    
    if number > confidentMin and number < confidentMax:
        print(data[0], "has red dot!")
    else:
        print(data[0], "has no red dot!")

    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(my_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB))
```

Comment: this object on horizontal image should have the smallest `height` - so you could rotate image a few angles, detect area used by object and check if his `height` is the smallest, if not then again rotate it, detect and check `height`, etc.

Comment: and similar with `translation` - you can detect area used by object and use only this area.

Comment: Where is camera poistion?

Comment: you're hard-coding those positions! of course you'll then have to position the board precisely. if you don't want to do that, you'll have to find the board and align the picture. you can do that with feature matching, or hope that "ECC refinement" (with enough gaussian blur) does the job.